# Automated emails generated from activities from address

Tags: activities

Is there a setting by which all emails from civi will have the same 'from' address? Specifically I am thinking of activity emails, where an activity is added by someone, and currently all emails sent out related to that activity show as being from that person, rather than from the default site email address. Is there a way to change this?

Even when a different person makes a change to an activity, the contact the activity was added by is used for the from address in the email alert.

This is especially relevant when someone leaves an organization, but there are still activities in progress that were added by that person. Of course the data that this person is who added/initiated the activity is valuable, but having emails sent from that person that is no longer in the organization is a problem.

Is there any method that could be employed in the UI that could address this? Or will we need to develop a patch to change what from email address is used for activity updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think civicrm uses the setting from `civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1`, i.e, Administer -> System Setting -> Outbound Email

[image]

If the above setting is enabled, civi uses the creator of the activity as a `from` address in all the email notification.

Set this to `No` in order to fix this problem.

Note that the above setting acts on your complete site and cannot be configured only for activities.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this setting, but the label did not draw me in as it being the solution. 

This will be adequate, though it would be better if there was a way to have the automated emails FROM address as the logged in user's address for activity updates, rather than the 'added by' contact, but perhaps that is better placed as a feature request/bug report in gitlab.